# Android: add overlay to MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I have subclassed Overlay as LandMarkOverlay (and implemented an onTap(GeoPoint) method).

In the main activity I do this:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    landmarkOverlay = new LandmarkOverlay();

    //add the landmarkOverlay to the list
    mapView.getOverlays().add(landmarkOverlay);
```

What else do I need to do so that when the user taps the screen, `landmarkOverlay`'s `onTap(GeoPoint)` method gets called?

Answer (score 0):

It should get called. I assume your method is `onTap(GeoPoint point, MapView mapView)`?